# Manage Windows 7 Tablet PC settings in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

In the Control Panel on Windows 7, I can reset calibration settings of the screen this way:

`Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Tablet PC Settings -> Display options -> Reset (button)`

[image: Tablet PC Settings popup]

Can this operation be performed in C#, without user interaction?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms924827(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), the following registry stores information for configuring the behavior of the touch screen.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Hardware\DeviceMap\Touch
```

`CalibrationData` is the value you need to reset, please try to modify this value with [Registry Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions). (It is recommended to make a backup before modifying the registry to avoid confusion of values)